# Django getting especific object using QuerySet in reverse relationship many-to-one

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, many-to-one

Lets say I have the following models:

```
Chat(models.Model):
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, related_name="chats", null=True, blank=True)
    ....

Community(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, default='')
    ....

Profile(models.Model):
    public_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    community_subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField('Community', through='CommunitySubscription')
    chat_subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField('Chat', through='ChatSubscription')
    ....

ChatSubscription(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, unique=False, related_name='chat_subscription')
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, null=True, blank=True, related_name='chat_subscribers')
    ....

CommunitySubscription(models.Model):
    ....
```

In a view I want to do the following:

```
profileA = Profile.objects.get(public_name=public_nameA)
profileB = Profile.objects.get(public_name=public_nameB)
community = Community.objects.get(slug=community_slug)

try:
    # I want to get the unique chat that involves both profiles for a specific community or get DoesNotExist (or None) if there is not such chat.
    chat = Chat.objects.????????????
except Chat.DoesNotExist:
    ....
```

If the chat exist then both profiles will have a ChatSubscription object relating the profile with the chat.

Is it possible to do this kind of filtering using Django QuerySets in one single line? If not what would be the most efficient way to do it in more than one line?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You want to get a chat that has a community that has both those profiles? I don't fully understand where the profiles come in.

Comment: I want to get a chat that has this specific two subscribers (thats where the profiles come in) and that belongs to one specific community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty complex, so try using the [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) to do a 'AND' query (assuming I got what you're trying to do):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Chat.objects.filter(Q(chatsubscription__profile__in=[profileA,profileB]) & Q(community=communty))
```

Comment: Looks good and yes, it seems you understood what I need! My only doubt: Will Q(chatsubscription__profile__in=[profileA,profileB]) check for both profileA and profileB being subscribers of the same Chat object or will it return Chat objects having either profilerA or profileB as suscribers?

Comment: Pretty sure it will check for both. So if either exists but not both it won't return anything, I've tried this with my own models before. But you can always test it in the shell to be sure!